# keeping database in sync ef core

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-migrations

I have read multiple posts about this but do not have a clear answer yet.
We are transitioning to EF Core 2.0 company-wide, one project at a time.

The challenge is this:

1. A new project starts and a database is created using code first, migrations etc.
2. another programmer needs to create a project targeting the same database.
3. This programmer can use Scaffold-DbContext and generate current models.
4. However, a new column is needed and this second programmer adds it.

Now...how do we best update the other projects?
Is there something that checks and syncs or shows what is out of sync between your model and a database?  Meaning check the database for changes...not the model.

We don't mind buying a tool if that is the best solution.

Comment: You can make a tool which will run `Add-Migration` command and check if its generating nonempty migration. If its generating empty migration then it means there is no changes in the model

Comment: I don't think that will catch if somebody else changed the database however, will it?

Comment: so whoever is changing the database, he/she is responsible to generate the changes in the model also or you have to run  `Scaffold-DbContext`. 
My advice would be don't mix code-first and DB-first approach together. If its necessary then manage multiple DBs

Comment: That is not a option.  We have a single database that is created by using code first.  Then another project needs to target that database.  My question is two fold:  First, should that person copy the models over by hand?  Second, no matter how the models get there we now have two projects using the same database and one or more projects WILL need to make changes.  How are other teams handling this problem?

Comment: Didnt get your point, can you make it more clear

Comment: See if other team is modifying models and generating migrations then you have to run `Scaffold-DbContext` to get the changes in your model from DB.

Comment: This is perhaps showing my ignorance, but I thought Scaffold-DbContext was only a one time thing?  Meaning, it would not update existing models but only create new ones the first time?  Is there a option to 'update' or 'refresh'?

Comment: It appears -force may do what I am looking for...?

Comment: U can try it, I’m out so can’t try locally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution we have been using, very successfully is the Database project in Visual Studio.

Using that each developer has the project in their solution, changes are made against it locally.
Then we can do a "Schema Compare" inside of VS.

We have been using this successfully for 4 of us the past three weeks extensively with almost no issues.

This has even worked for keeping versions and changes to our stored procedures current.
It works well with VSTS also.

Here are some of the posts I read that helped me understand it:

https://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2016/1/10/why-you-should-use-a-ssdt-database-project-for-your-data-warehouse

https://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/using-visual-studio-database-projects-in-real-life

..and this forum had a lot of relevant questions/answers:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-us/home?forum=ssdt